# How to hide a div and disable the links inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, hyperlink

I have a one `<div>` with links in it and another `<div>` below the first one.

I want the first one to disappear, so that:

- the second `<div>` does not move. So the jQuery function `.hide()` is not what I look for.
- the links become inactive in the first div.

Is it possible to do that, using javascript or jQuery ?

PS : if it is not possible, I am interested of the other option where :

- the first `<div>` hides.
- the second `<div>` moves gradually.

Thank you,

Colas

edit 2 :

You can look at this fidle http://jsfiddle.net/XKMEp/5/ to see what I tried to do.

edit : Here my attempts

```
$("#div1").click(function() {       
    /*actus.fadeOut('slow');*/
    actus.fadeTo(1000,0).delay(1001).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    $('input,textarea,select,a', '#div1').attr("disabled", true);
});
```

even this does not work :

```
$("#div1").click(function() {       
    /*actus.fadeOut('slow');*/
    actus.fadeTo(1000,0).delay(1001).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    $('input,textarea,select,a', '#div1').attr("disabled", true);
});
```

And let's say my html code is :

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
</div>
    <div class="container">
<div id="div2"></div>
</div>


.container{width:300px;height:300px;}
```

Comment: If you don't want the second div to move when the first is hidden, use the CSS style `visibility: hidden;`, that way the element still takes up room on the page when "hidden".

Comment: just position your divs absolutely and hide them the way you wanted.

Comment: And for moving the second div gradually, you can use the `slide` animations of jQuery - `slideUp` would probably be used.

Comment: Where is your html code?

Comment: you can find the sol here: http://jsfiddle.net/XKMEp/

Comment: whats actus? one of the elements?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed... wasn't giving up. Yes it needs to be the opacity (well fade to opacity for cross browser) to keep the position but one line of jquery does it. http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/XKMEp/24/

All you have to do is change the fermer to a tags instead of divs and restyle them a bit to get them where you had them.

```
    $(".fermer").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').fadeTo('slow',0);
    });
​

     <a href="#" class="fermer">
         fermer
     </a>
```

Comment: Wow ! I didn't know fiddle ! Its great :) I removed the empty function from your fidle (in the js) and it still works. What's the use of this empty function ? Thank you !

Comment: nothing, I removed it after too, it had another event in it that alerted the function was done straight from jQuery site lol.

Comment: You didn't put them inside their containing divs. Each one you want to close has to be inside the container div which has a set height.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/XKMEp/12/  fixed your cursor on fermer too.

Comment: the problem is that my divs dont have a fixed height.

Comment: So after all that you downvoted me because you didn't notice that I said set height in the answer? Sometimes I really wonder why I bother coming here.

Comment: Sad how often that happens randomly with no explanation. See this fiddle, you have to add the padding and margin to the height but it works. It does NOT work with the hide though since it scrolls up it looks silly http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/XKMEp/20/ Ugh... nvm no it won't it will only work for the first one, sorry go with the opacity answer

Comment: Its okay for the first two blocks. But the third one creates problems. (see http://jsfiddle.net/XKMEp/23/) Thanks anyway. I dont have enough reputation to vote.

Comment: Grrr... look at the edit, tell me this works. lol you should be able to add as many divs as you want and that SHOULD work.

Comment: Great ! Do you know why the following does not work (not gradual) ? `$(".fermer").click(function() {
  divAssociee = $(this).closest('div');
     divAssociee.fadeTo(1000,0).delay(1000);
  divAssociee.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });`

Comment: Yeah the visibility hidden is firing before the animation can complete. This however does, since it doesn't fire the visibility function until the fade is done $(".fermer").click(function() { divAssociee = $(this).closest('div'); divAssociee.fadeTo(1000,0).delay(1000), function(){ divAssociee.css('visibility', 'hidden'); };;});​

Comment: I replace `delay` by `setTimeout`: `$(".fermer").click(function() {
  divAssociee = $(this).closest('div');
  divAssociee.fadeTo(1000, 0);
  setTimeout(function() {
   divAssociee.css('visibility', 'hidden')
  },1000);
 });` and I dont know why IT WORKS !

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! it is now 3:11am and I get up at 6 so... gnight lol.

Comment: My final choice : `$(".fermer").click(function() {
  divAssociee = $(this).closest('div');
  divAssociee.fadeTo(1000, 0, function() {
   divAssociee.css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
 });`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make a div the same size but if you want to use a JavaScript solution, you can always use `removeAttr('href')` to disable the links and change the opacity to 0. This will give the appearance that the `div` is removed but it is still there with the same height without altering the CSS.

```
$('#first').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('opacity', '0');
    $(this).children('a').removeAttr('href');        
}​​​​​​​​);​
```

Here's the [jsFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/4aZwk/). You can also reenable everything if you store the links in a data attribute or id or something similar.

Comment: opacity isn't cross browser compatible, you'd need to add one for moz then the filters for IE for that to work across the board.

Comment: Opacity is pretty cross browser compatible (see [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=opacity)). But sure, if cross-browser compatibility is an issue, you could easily swap that line for a fadeTo(). The idea was to use opacity to "remove" the element.

Comment: @RickCalder I think opacity is fine, except for the one extra style you have to add for IE

Comment: I tried but it does not work. See the blue block in the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XKMEp/16/. The links are still active.

Comment: That may be because the links aren't direct children. You may use find('a') instead if that makes it easier. http://jsfiddle.net/XKMEp/17/

Comment: Great, it works ! So find('a') checks for the children and their descendants, isn't it ?

Comment: You probably want to use `"visibility", "hidden"` instead of `opacity`. If you use `opacity`, you can still click on the element, while `visibility` truly makes it hidden/inaccessible.

Comment: @Colas Well, children are descendents, so yes :)

Comment: Can you expand your idea Ian ?

Comment: @Colas Ian's right. You simply have to change the `visibility` to `hidden` and that will keep the size of the box AND disable everything within it. That's actually the better solution in this problem.
`$(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');`

Comment: @koostudios Can you expand about reenabling ?

Comment: You can reenable the visibility by just changing `hidden` to `visible`. e.g. `$("#div1").css('visibility', 'visible');`

Comment: `$(div1).style.visibility = "hidden";` doesnt work but `$(div1).css('visibility', 'hidden');` works. Why ? Can I make the disappearing effect gradual ?

Comment: You can't access the style namespace using the jQuery selector (which is the first one), that only works if you use vanilla JS such as `document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility etc.`. The second works using a jQuery method to do the same thing just shorter.

Comment: So, `document.getElementById('div1')` and `$('div1')` are not equal ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#second').css({"visibility":"hidden"});
  $('#firstdiv a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
      }             
);
```

Comment: How would that stop the second div from moving to take the place of the missing div?

Comment: Dont you mean '#div1' ? I want the links of the first div to be inactive.

Comment: $('#firstdiv a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
      }

Answer (score 0):

see my demo here, 
use style.visibility for your goal
use style.display if you want to move the 2nd div's position;
(however, this one is not gradually)

```
<html>
<head>

<title>div test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function show(){
document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";

}
function change1(){
document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
function change2(){
document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
}


</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="div1" style="background:red; height:50px">
    first div: <a href="http://www.hetaoblog.com" target="_blank">a link to http://www.hetaoblog.com</a>
</div>

<div>
    2nd div    allaala   <br />
    <button onclick="show()">show</button>   <br />
    <button onclick="change1()">change1</button>   <br />
    <button onclick="change2()">change2</button>   <br />

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you could add your code for better understanding of your question.

Typically

```
style="display:none;" //will hide the div
style="display:block;" //will display the div
```

or

```
style="visibility:hidden" //will hide the div
style="visibility:visible" //will display the div
```

In order to trigger these u could use a javascript (but first of all the div should be have ID's)

```
<script>
ns4 = (document.layers) ? true:false
ie4 = (document.all) ? true:false 
ng5 = (document.getElementById) ? true:false

// Works for all browsers irrespective of its release date :p

function hidediv() {
if (ng5) document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility = "hidden"
else if (ns4) document.div1.visibility = "hide"
else if (ie4) div1.style.visibility ="hidden"
}

function showdiv(n){
if (ng5) document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility = "visible";
else if (ns4) document.div1.visibility = "show";
else if (ie4) div1.style.visibility = "visible";
</script>
```

Call the functions to hide/show div's

Answer (score -1):

Use this type structure

```
<div id="main">
 <div id="first">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link">Hide</a>
</div>
<div id="second">
 content
</div>
</div><!-- Main div -->
```

Jquery

```
 $("#link").click(function() {
  $("#first").hide();
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't do what he asked and you have no trigger for the jquery. May want to reread the question.